# How to convert string[] to List<UserType>, using linq?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq

// Example: `path = "C:\Users\MSI\Desktop\1.jpg"`

`There is an array and list`:

1. `string[] files = new string[] {"path1", "path2", "path3"};`
2. `List<UserType> mainFileList = new List<UserType>();`

I don't want to describe the whole loop (for, foreach, ...) every time, I want to convert data from string[] to List in short form. How to do it using Linq?

```
public class UserType{
  // Public fields
  public readonly string FullPath;
  public readonly string Name;

  public UserType() { }
    public UserType(string fullPath) {
      FullPath = fullPath;
      Name = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ:

```
string[] files = new string[] {"path1", "path2", "path3"};
List<UserType> mainFileList = files.Select(f => new UserType(f)).ToList();
```

But actually, there will still be a loop, which is now hidden in the `Select` method.

Comment: Technically the loop is in the `ToList`.  All `Select` does is create the `IEnumerable` that `ToList` will loop over.